# Как правильно использовать общие методы для Unit тестов?

Tags: юнит-тесты, junit, java-8

Есть несколько классов с Unit тестами.
В каждом классе тесты должны использовать метод чтения из файлов

```
public static String readFromFile(String fileName){
    String result = null;
    ClassLoader classLoader = MessageKafkaHandlerTest.class.getClassLoader();

    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(ls);
        }

        result = stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Куда и как корректно вынести этот метод? 
Какой правильный подход для решения таких задач?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: можно примеры методов (хотя бы их сигнатур) где этот метод будет использоваться и какая функциональность теститруется?

Comment: метод чтения добавил в описание вопроса. Используется для чтения SQL запроса из файла только для тестов. Далее этот прочитанный запрос в тесте сравнивается с запросом который возвращает тестируемый метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать новый класс типа `TestFileUtils` в том пакете, который содержит ваши тесты. Если тесты находятся в разных пакетах, то выберите самый верхний родительский.

Один совет по вышеприведенному коду:

Не игнорируйте `IOException`. От того, что вы выводите stack trace на консоль, ваш тест не станет красным, а надеятся что кто-то заметит это глазами не стоит. Лучше выбросить оригинальный `IOException` как есть, т.е. дайте тесту свалиться.
Еще как вариант можно валить тест прямо в `catch` с помощью `fail()`:

```
catch (IOException e) {
  fail("Could not read resource file: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: TestFileUtils у него должны быть какие-то аннотации как у родительского, или его достаточно просто наследовать?

Comment: Аннотации не нужны и наследоваться от не него не нужно, используйте вот так: `TestFileUtils.readFromFile(...)`.